# how to handle the signal Ctrl + Z in mini-shell. C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to suspend the process but it doesn't work. 
this is part of code. there are Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C. Ctrl+C is working. I cannot get why with Z it doesn't work.
(the actual code):

```
//ctrl+Z
void sigstop(int p){
    signal(SIGTSTP,&sigstop);
    kill(my_pid,SIGSTOP);

    fflush(stdout);
}

// Ctrl+C
void sigkill(int p){
    signal(SIGINT,&sigkill);  
    kill(my_pid,SIGKILL);

    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Code in the main method:

```
...
my_pid = fork();    
if (my_pid == 0) {
    signal(SIGTSTP,&sigstop);      //for Ctrl+Z
    signal(SIGINT,&sigkill);       //for Ctrl+C

    checkCommand();        
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    exit(getpid());    
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `fflush` on `stdin` as this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your `sigstop` and `sigkill` functions need to take an `int` parameter: your compiler should be giving you warnings about the wrong function signature.

Comment: You shouldn't have to register a handler for `SIGTSTP` because the default behavior is to stop the process.

Comment: yeah, actually I changed the code before. it has stdout, and I have also put int as a parameter. but its still not working. mistakenly I put older code.

Comment: what about  SIGTSTP? what should I do with that?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of installing signal handlers for `SIGTSTP` and `SIGINT`, put the terminal into raw mode with `cfmakeraw` or `tcsetattr`.  <kbd>^C</kbd> and <kbd>^Z</kbd> will then be readable as ordinary characters, which should be much less troublesome.  However, you will then need to implement line-editing yourself -- [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) is your friend there.  For further advice, please see the [Implementing a Shell](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html) and [Job Control](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html) sections of the [GNU C Library Manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/index.html).  (You can safely ignore the part where it tries to warn you that job control might not be supported by the kernel -- if anyone is still using one of *those* systems anymore, they have only themselves to blame for it.)

Comment: you should use http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/ instead of GNU readline, but good answer.

Comment: @GoodPerson Is there any actual advantage of editline besides the more permissive license? (This is not a rhetorical question, I don't know.)

Comment: @Zack - I've seen reduced memory usage; other than the more free license there isn't a big difference though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that calling kill() in the sigkill function, just begins an infinite, recursive loop where the kill() just calls again the sigkill function, which calls kill() which calls again sigkill function... etc... Instead of calling kill(), set a global boolean variable and check for it in your main function. If this global boolean variable is set, you just exit gracefully.

Something like:

```
volatile bool gTerminate = false;

void sigkill(int p)
{
    gTerminate = true;
    signal(SIGINT, &sigkill);  
}

int main(...)
{
   //initialization stuff...

   while( !gTerminate )
   {
      //do stuff
   }

   return -1;
}
```

Comment: If anyone reads this, read carefully. Each signal handler in the question does call `kill`, so does send a signal. But. It sends *not* the signal it handles. Moreover, the signals sent are those that are *never* delivered to the program, but are handled by the kernel instead. (There are exactly 2 such signals in Linux: SIGKILL and SIGSTOP).

Comment: But when you are in a kernel thread, you can catch those two as well, and do funny things when someone tries to kill -9 that thread :)